# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. - error at user register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to do a user register, but when I go to send the information to database this error appear "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." What can I do to resolve this problem? Do I have to change the routes on web.php?

**CONTROLLER** -- AdmController.php

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('cadastros.cad_user');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(isset($request['adm']))
        {
            $checkbox = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $checkbox = 0;
        }
        User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make('29recogna03'),
            'adm' => $checkbox,
            'ativo' => 1,
            'maquina' => '',
        ]);

        return view('cadastros/cad_user');
    }
```

**ROUTE** -- web.php

```
Route::post('/cadastro', [App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('/cad_user', [App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, 'create']);
```

**VIEW** -- cad_user.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Cadastro de usuários')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="cardRegister">
                

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('cadastro') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="title">
                            <h3><b>CADASTRAR USUÁRIO</b></h3>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" placeholder="Nome do usuário" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group dec">
                            <div class="ger"><p>Usuário</p></div>
                                <div class="switch__container">
                                    <input id="switch-flat" class="switch switch--flat" type="checkbox" name="adm" value="1">
                                    <label for="switch-flat"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="func"><p>Administrador</p></div>   
                            
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" value="29recogna03" disabled>

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('CADASTRAR') }}
                        </button>

                    </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Your template says `route('cadastro')` but you have not named your routes.

Comment: Open up your browser's developer tools/network tab when submitting the form, and make sure you don't have any sort of redirect going on, such as HTTP -> HTTPS. That will change the method from POST to GET.

Answer (score 4):

Helper function `route` works based on **route names**, but you have forgotten to add your route name, change your route to the following:

```php
Route::post('/cadastro', [App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, 'store'])->name('cadastro');
```

**Update**

As [Aynber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007220/aynber) mentioned, in normal cases if you had not that route name, it would throw `Route [route-name] not defined` error. Since it does not show that error, you might already have a route with that name, run `php artisan route:list` and see which route is named that and just fix namings based on your logic.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause an error on the view instead?  Giving `Route [route-name] not defined`

Comment: @aynber You are right about that, I think she shows the route files partially and has a route named that. Updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: I named the route the way @aynber mentioned ( Route::post('/cadastro', [App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, 'store'])->name('cadastro'); ) but it still persists in the same error

Comment: @MohsenNazari I run in the terminal php artisan route:list but shows that the method being used is POST, but the error says I'm using the GET method.

Answer (score 1):

```
you have to name your route like the following
Route::post('/cadastro', [App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, 'store'])->name('cadastro');
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong, you are calling as get method in post method routing just change your calling method from GET =>POST if you are using form then use POST in method instead of GET or blank method name

Answer (score 0):

Add a route name or just change form action to `action="/cadastro"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in the route file

```
Route::post('/cadastro', [App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, 'store'])->name('cadastro');
```

or you can make resource route like below

```
Route::resource('cadastro', App\Http\Controllers\AdmController::class, ['names' => 'cadastro'])->only(['create', 'store']);
```